# How to add django admin read-only permissions?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How to add read-only permissions in `Model` in django?

By default there are three permissions available for users `Can add`, `Can delete`, `Can change`.

How to add `Can read` permission in `Model` in Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First solution

You didn't specify your django version, but i suppose you are in Django 1.x, as starting django 2.x there are four default permissions : `add`, `change`, `delete`, and the new one `view`, which is the one your are interested in.
So a first solution (maybe not the easiest), is to upgrade to django 2.x, and use the `view` permission.

### Second solution

Second solution, you can add the permissions you want to use for each model in the Meta, as described in the docs : [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#permissions).

```
permissions = (("can_read", "Can read"),)
```

### Side note

Note that you can also edit the default permissions by model, by using the default_permissions key. [See default-permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#default-permissions).

Answer (score 0):

As documentation [custom permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions) indicates, you can define custom permissions on model's meta class.

```
class Task(models.Model):
...
class Meta:
    permissions = (
        ("change_task_status", "Can change the status of tasks"),
        ("close_task", "Can remove a task by setting its status as closed"),
    )
```